# node mqtt server not propagating publishings

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt

in [this sample project](https://github.com/sombriks/sample-mqtt) i am trying to subscribe to a channel and publish into it.

However i never get back the message sent to the broker.

This is the server:

```
const mqttServer = require("mqtt-server");

const servers = mqttServer(
    {
        mqtt: "tcp://localhost:1883",
        mqttws: "ws://localhost:1884",
    },
    {
        emitEvents: true, // default
    },
    client => {
        console.log("client connected!");
        // console.log(client)
        client.connack({
            returnCode: 0,
        });
        client.on("data", data => {
      console.log("got data: ");
      console.log(data);
      client.puback({messageId:data.packetId, ...data})
    });


    client.on("error", err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
    },
);

servers.listen(_ => {
    console.log("listening!");
});

servers.close(_ => {
    console.log("close!");
});
```

And this is the client:

```
const mqtt = require("mqtt");

const client = mqtt.connect("mqtt://localhost:1883");

client.on("connect", ack => {
    console.log("connected!");
    // console.log(ack);
    client.subscribe("/test", err => {
        console.log(err);
    });

    client.on("message", (topic, message) => {
        console.log(topic);
        // message is Buffer
        console.log(message.toString());
    });

    setInterval(_ => {
        client.publish("/test", "Hello mqtt");
    }, 3000);
});

client.on("error", err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Any thoughts on what am i missing?

Comment: Topics should not start with”/“ - that is adding an extra topic level and is bad practice see https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-5-mqtt-topics-best-practices/. Have you tried with a commandline publisher or subscriber to test that your broker is in fact working?

Comment: hi @barny i changed the broker and it's working now, thanks for the link, it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that using [aedes](https://github.com/mcollina/aedes) broker the scenario on the sample project worked just fine!